# Cannot resolve symbol DownloaderService for APK expansion

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I was following this guide :
https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

and in my downloaderService.java file it can't resolve to extends **DownloaderService** :

```
public class downloaderService extends DownloaderService {
```

Why and how to fix it?
another file can't resolve **DownloaderClientMarshaller** at alarmReceiver.java :

```
..  DownloaderClientMarshaller.startDownloadServiceIfRequired(context,
                    intent, downloaderService.class);  .....
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: did you add `compile 'com.google.android.`??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no, because it's not instructed in the page.. which dependencies I should add?

Answer (score 1):

Google tutorial not worked for me, and neither this one:
https://kitefaster.com/2017/02/15/expansion-apk-files-android-studio/

Because after import the libraries I had the same problem that you.

But adding dependencies in gradle worked for me. For that you have to add in your app build.gradle this lines:

```
android{
     [...]
     repositories {
         maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/alexeydanilov/apk-expansion'}
     }
}

dependencies {
      compile 'com.danikula.expansion:expansion:1.3.4'
      compile 'com.danikula.expansion:license:1.7.0'
      compile 'com.danikula.expansion:zip:1.2.1'
}
```

As you can see here:
https://github.com/danikula/Google-Play-Expansion-File

And finally android studio finds vending library and DownloaderService and DownloaderClientMarshaller classes.

Hope this answer help you :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. But I don't understand why they're being hosted at that other different domain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following libraries as modules to your project:

- Google Play Licencing Library package
- Google Play APK Expansion Library package

as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#Preparing) in the android developers website